# I get this error with js function stating that it is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const value = document.querySelector("#value");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

btns.forEach(function (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

});

> this says that this button function is not defined

Comment: What is the exact error? ``button`` is never written in the code you sent?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include the script in your html file and make sure to install the required npm packages

Answer (score 0):

the buttons that you have in the array are not functions but javascript objects

So it should be

```
btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
 });
```